# js background image same window size

Tags: javascript, html, background, fullscreen

I'm trying to make these images the same size of the window. 
I'm using some js code to make the background dynamic. I'm not able to align this element in the center and self-scaling.
Any help?
Many thanks

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds){
//change the image
if(!imageID){
    document.getElementById("myimage").src="http...0.jpg";
    imageID++;
}
else{if(imageID==1){
    document.getElementById("myimage").src="http...1.jpg";
    imageID++;
}}
//call same function again for x of seconds
setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
}
</script>
<link href="baba.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body style='background:#f1f2f4;  height:100%; width:100%; text-align:center;      position:absolute; ' onload='changeimage(2)'>
<img id='myimage' src='http...3.jpg'/>



</body>





</html>
```

Now the image is not responsive at all

Comment: I think you want to make the image size as body's size.?

Comment: when you are calling this function first time?
id didn't saw the first function call.. all i saw is a definition of it... correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I don't get it. Why not set width/height of the img to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery and then:

```
$("img").css("position", "absolute").css("top", 0).css("left", 0).css("bottom", 0).css("right", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place a `<div>` tag instead of an `<img>` tag and set up the background properties of the div.

```
div#image-container{

background-image:url(http:/yoururl.com/image.jpg);
height:400px;
width:600px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 400px 600px;

}
```

You would have to change your changeimage function so that it changes the background-image url.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with CSS.
Changing the background-image with Javascript if necessary.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```